# I have an LED scoreboard that no longer connects with its remote, would it be possible to mod it to run over wifi being controled by a RPi

Tags: led, connection

[image]

I was wondering if this type of scoreboard could be controlled by a pi wirelessly as the wireless remote has stopped working.

Comment: Ultimately, the answer is yes. Technically, there is allot of work first. Was the remote Wifi or IR? Is there a LAN interface, Serial Interface, any interface??

Comment: It is difficult to say without more information.  I note that the URL on the bottom of the scoreboard is for www.maudesport.com which is valid and goes to a company (Maudesport Sports Equipment) in Walsall in the West Midlands of the U.K.  I was not able to spot this exact model on their website but the descriptions for others do suggest that a direct wired connection may be possible as well - hacking that or the wireless link though really depends on working out the protocol used.  The scoreboard in the image looks as though it has crashed - have you tried switching it off-and-on again? 8-)

Comment: Have you slapped the soul out of your remote? If you did and it still doesn't work, change the batteries. Make sure the new ones are really fresh batteries and not pulled from another dying remote.

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible.

**If an interface is available (LAN, WiFi, Serial)**

- Send the appropriate commands using said interface. You may want to consult the scoreboard's manual/datasheet/manufacturer.

**If there is no interface available:**

- Figure out how the LEDs get driven. I bet it's the same with a [seven-segment display.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-a-7-segment-4-digit-display-with-a-Ras/?ALLSTEPS) If it's not and there are too many LEDs to handle (you only have 28 available GPIO pins), [use a shift register.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Using-a-shift-register-with-Raspberry-Pi/?ALLSTEPS)
- Figure out how to drive the LEDs itself, though it may be as simple as just using a MOSFET/transistor to bump up the voltage/current (GPIO can only give out 3.3V, 16mA each, 51mA total if using multiple pins). It may be a good idea to visit [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- Whip up a simple script to accept commands via WiFi and trigger the appropriate GPIO pins. I really like [using Node.JS in these situations](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/raspberry-pi-node-js-led-emit-morse-code/), but I fear it may be too slow (or not).